# What are the major Catholic academic journals?

Tags: catholicism

Here's a question for the community wiki. What are the top 10 Catholic academic journals in English? I can think of a few (*The Thomist*, *Nova et Vetera*, *Catholic Biblical Quarterly*), but I haven't been able to find a list anywhere. I'm looking for the top ten scholarly journals, sorted roughly by readership or some other criterion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What are the major Catholic academic journals in English?**

The following list is some of the major Catholic academic journals. One can not establish which ones are the most major ones with any established certitude!

**General**

- [*American Catholic Philosophical Quarterly*](https://www.pdcnet.org/acpq)
- [*Communio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communio)
- [*Horizons: The Journal of the College Theology Society*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizons_(journal))
- [*Logos: A Journal of Catholic Thought and Culture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos:_A_Journal_of_Catholic_Thought_and_Culture)
- [*Lumen Veritatis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_Veritatis)
- [*Newman Studies Journal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman_Studies_Journal)
- [*Nova et Vetera*](https://stpaulcenter.com/academic-projects/nova-et-vetera-journal/)
- [*Philosophy and Theology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_and_Theology)
- [*The New Scholasticism*](https://www.pdcnet.org/newscholas)
- [*The Thomist*](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/explore.htm)
- [*Theological Studies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theological_Studies_(journal))
- [*Thought: Fordham University Quarterly*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought:_Fordham_University_Quarterly)

**Scripture**

- [*Catholic Biblical Quarterly*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Biblical_Quarterly)

**Bioethics**

- *National Catholic Bioethics Quarterly*
- *Linacre Quarterly*
- *[Catholic Medical Quarterly](http://www.cmq.org.uk/)*

Comment: This community wiki answer can be be added to by anyone who desires to.